# Google Drive API - Notifications

Tags: google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/drive/push says that I can receive notifications for a specific domain that I have registered. Is it possible to receive notifications about the changes in files in Google Drive?

Finding it hard to understand what can be done using Google Drive API. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notification enables you to write a service hosted on a verified domain, for every change that meets your subscription, a call to that service is made by Google Drive servers.

On Google Drive's [Github](https://github.com/googledrive/pushnotifications-playground) you can find a pushnotification playground with a video that explains and show what can be done with the push notification.

Let me know if I misunderstood something as the question was not really specific

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the link. I was looking for something like that.